# What would the penalty for this be?

Tags: plot-explanation, realism, scarface

In the beginning of *Scarface*, when he realizes the Miami authorities have figured out he did time in Cuba, Tony says he was imprisoned for "buying dollars"- someone on Movie Mistakes told me this meant he was "buying US dollars from tourists or business people and selling them to refugees who are willing to pay far above the normal exchange rate to have American money for when they attempt to flee Cuba to America."

Assuming for a moment this was the crime Tony was imprisoned for, and not something more violent- what kind of sentence would this offence likely get?

Comment: This is question for either Law.se or History.se.